# ASP.NET API Question: How do I add an existing subscriber to an additional list?

Tags: api

How do I add an existing subscriber to an additional list?  I am using asp.net api.  I am able to add new subscribers to the list using code like this:

https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_subscribers_to_a_list/

However, if I try to subscribe a user that is already in exact target to a new list, they dont get added.

saveOption.SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateAdd; does not help.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I created a new GUID.

string strGUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

I then assigned this new id as the subscriber key
sub.SubscriberKey = strGUID; //required //may not be active in all accounts //some choose to set this to email address

Well, once I changed it to be the user's email address instead of a new GUID is worked!